# I need this regex expression to ignore HTML tags

Tags: regex

I created this search function highlight term and replace function, but I need the regex to ignore and not hightlight the HTML tags. Could some one show how to do this and edit my regex to get it to work? - Needs to work in chrome and firefox

````
    return new RegExp('(</?[^>]*|&[^;]*)?(?![<>/_?.]|&amp)(' + term.replace(/[-/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&') + ')', 'gi');
  };``` .               ```const searchTermsInArray = this.state.searchKeyword.trim().split(' ');
      searchTermsInArray.forEach(term => {
        if (term.length) {
          const regexp = this.regexpFormula(term);
          newQuestion.qtiData.prompt = newQuestion.qtiData.prompt.replace(regexp, match => {
            return `<span class="highlight">${match}</span>`;
          });```

It hightlights and replaces fine, the issue is what I search p it removes the p and highlights the whole sentence not the search term.
````

Comment: Hello! It is impossible to [parse HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1758162/9642811). Thanks!

Comment: I don't need it to parse it I just need it to ignore it / skip the tags.  its possible because I had it working before, however it only worked in chrome and not firefox so I had to change somethings around and now can't get it to work again

Comment: for example ``` regexpFormula = term => {
    return new RegExp(`(?!<|>|/|&amp|_)(?<!</?[^>]*|&[^;]*)(${term})`, 'gi');
  };``` . this works in chrome but not in firefox and this ignores the html tags @MilkyWay90

Comment: Or you could use a HTML parser in your programming language. What tags are you trying to skip over?

Comment: p, h, br tags im trying to get it to ignore anything within the < > @MilkyWay90

Comment: Have you looked over the docs for a valid tag?

Comment: im not sure what you mean @MilkyWay90

Comment: Have you looked over the HTML specification to know what characters can be in a tag?

Comment: I think you might be missing the point  I need the regex to skip over the <' '> (search this ) . < >  <--- skip the carrots so the regex needs to ignore any carrots @MilkyWay90

Comment: Such a regex would require lookaheads and lookbehinds (as you are using in your example), however [lookbehinds are not yet supported in Firefox (among others)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Browser_compatibility). You'll probably have to look for a non-javascript solution for now, or find a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Regular Expression to ignore all HTML tags with properties:

```
<\s*a[^>]*>|<\s*/\s*a>
```

Comment: how would I add or rather where would I put that in this expression ```new RegExp('(</?[^>]*|&[^;]*)?(?![<>/_]|&amp)(' + term.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&') + ')', 'gi');``` @Vijay Pendse